# TortoiseCVS quits with the message > cvs [log aborted]: the :extssh: access method is not available on this system

Tags: cvs, tortoisecvs

When I try to commit to repository via CVS I get the error message

```
cvs [log aborted]: the :extssh: access method is not available on this system
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on the information that I found in

http://blog.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.cvs.tortoisecvs.user/month=20080701/page=2

http://customer.march-hare.com/webtools/bugzilla/ttshow_bug.cgi?tt=1&id=4918

and

http://www.cvsnt.org/pipermail/cvsnt/2007-March/028600.html

You can solve this problem if you change the line

extssh = ssh_protocol.dll

to

extssh = ssh.dll

in the file **C:\Program Files (x86)\CVSNT\protocol_map.ini** *(Windows 7)*

and move the file to

**C:\Program Files (x86)\CVSNT\protocols\protocol_map.ini** *(Windows 7)*

Hope this helps somebody

Comment: getting `cvs [update aborted]: writing to server socket: error -1` then -(